# Lotus Notes - Save mail to file with OLE

Tags: email, save, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ole

I am accessing Lotus Notes via OLE, and this is how I retrieve the selected mail:

```
try
 UIView := FLNotes.CURRENTVIEW; // am I in a view or in an opened document ?
 if VarIsClear(UIView) then begin
   try
     aDocument := FLNotes.CURRENTDOCUMENT.Document;

   except
       raise;
   end;
 end else begin  // any selected mails in view ?

   UIDocuments := UIView.DOCUMENTS;

   for counter := 1 to UIDocuments.Count do begin
     if counter = 1 Then
       aDocument := UIDocuments.GETFIRSTDOCUMENT
     else
       aDocument := UIDocuments.GETNEXTDOCUMENT(aDocument);

   end;
 end;
finally
 UIView := Unassigned;
 UIDocuments := Unassigned;
 aDocument := Unassigned;
end;
```

I have the reference to the particular mail in `aDocument`. Now I would like to save every each mail (on the disk as a file, not inside Lotus Notes), but I didnt find the right method to use with OLE. 
I have found this  [Notes Commands](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FILESAVE.html), but I didnt figure out whats the syntax for OLE access. I tried it like this: `aDocument.Command("FileSave", "Test.eml")`, and I tried also lot of other combinations with `Save` but none of them worked. So maybe somebody did this already or has a tip where I could look for a solution

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a way to save the mail as an eml file (actually any file that you want, but since .eml is what I need I will use that). So for any case somebody may need it here the code :

```
 try
   oleSession := GetActiveOleObject('Notes.NotesSession');
 except
   oleSession := CreateOleObject('Notes.NotesSession');
 end;

 path := '...Somepath.../Mail.eml';

 oleDB := oleSession.CurrentDatabase;

 oleSession.ConvertMIME := false; 

 oleView := GetSelectedMail; //the code for this is in the first post

 oleDoc := oleView.GetFirstDocument;
 oleDoc.converttomime(1); 

 mime := oleDoc.getmimeentity;

 oleEmailText := oleSession.CreateStream; // create a stream to fill it with the data

 oleEmailText.open(path, 'us-ascii'); 

 mime.GetEntityAsText(oleEmailText); // write inside stream

 oleSession.ConvertMIME := true; // put this flag back to its original state - per default its true -
```

Just as a side note, with this method attachments are missing from the saved mail. But since I separate them and save inside another folder, its not a big issue for my case

Regards

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think the NotesStream class was available via the OLE classes - only via the COM classes - but the COM classes couldn't have gotten you the selected documents from the view, so I didn't even really consider them. This probably isn't going to generate the exact same format for the .eml as you'll get from the manual drag-drop, but it will be close enough. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Save operations in Notes will save a document in an NSF file, not the filesystem. It's an Export operation you would be looking for.

- The `FileSave` command saves a currently open-for-edit document in the
  Notes UI and saves it to the NSF file that it was opened from.
- The `Save` method similarly does a back-end save - i.e., it bypasses the UI operations, takes the in-memmory representation of an existing Notes document (not necessarily the one that is current in the Notes client), and saves it to the NSF file that it was opened from.

Back to the subject of Export operations, as far as I know, there is no supported Export method for .eml files. Although the Notes client can save a .eml file if you drag a message from a view and drop it on your desktop, I don't believe there is any supported method in any of the supported Notes APIs for automating this process. (In theory, I imagine that one might be able to use the Windows API to send the appropriate event messages to the Notes client in order to make it think the user is doing a drag-and-drop operation, but that's way beyond the scope of what could possibly be addressed here on StackOverflow.)

Comment: If there is no API, where could I lookup those Windows API-s so I can find the right way to imitate a drag and drop ? But I must admit that its a bit strange that nobody nevery needed to - automated - save a mail from lotus notes physically ...

Comment: I suppose I should have said flat out that I don't recommend trying that. It will be a huge amount of work, and if it works at all it is still pretty likely to break anytime a new release of Notes or Windows comes out. And I don't mean to be insulting, but if you don't already know Windows API programming to the level that you already know about event messages and how to send them, you almost certainly should not try this.

Comment: That said, this is the API call that I'm talking about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx, You'll need to know much, much more than that to even begin, and as I said above, that sort of information is way beyond the scope of Q&A here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Regarding your comment about it being strange that nobody needs to do this... Lots of people need to, and many have done it. There's just no simple API.  People have written their own code to read the data in Notes format and create the .eml file (or other formats) by hand. This is not simple. People sell products that do it.

Comment: Othe implementations have used a combination of custom software and some complex tricks to get Lotus' email system to re-mail a copy of the message to an SMTP system that receives it - and then they run even more software to strip off whatever was added to the email in that process. So there are lots of ways it's been done, but no simple API that anyone can point you to.

Comment: Actually I am using Windows API on some other occasions (Active Directory access, or sending messages between my 2 applications). I was more looking for the right parameter call, but in the end you are right, I didnt think it would be that much effort and this thing with Lotus Notes is taking more time then i thought (I am comming from the Outlook world). Strange thing, I somehow managed to save the .eml file when I did my first steps with Lotus Notes, but when I tried to open it (with dbl click) I got the message "You need more rights" inside Notes (but the .eml was open inside Notes)

Comment: If you say that many people need it and need to build complex stuff to just save the mail, I am even more wondering why IBM is not doing anything about that and offer some propper way. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help, I will decide if its worth the struggle, and if it is, I will have to find a solution :)

Comment: You are probably thinking of Notes as an email system so it would make sense to produce .eml, but to customers and to IBM it is much more. .eml really isn't a very good way to represent Notes data - not even internal Notes email. You might as well be asking why IBM doesn't provide the ability to save to PDF, or to 100 other formats! IBM provide lower-level APIs that allow companies that build enterprise solutions for migration, archiving, compliance, and similar things to build their own converters to lots of different formats. That's what makes the most sense for them.